# How to hide a grid-view column for different users roles in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

There is no error showing! It's not functioning!

I need to hide this `UserID` column for this UserType when he logins "Stock_Controller". And make it visible for "Administrator".

I have a grid-view with columns of items as follows:

```
ID|Stock_Type|Stock_No|No_of_pieces|Gem_Type|Weight|Image|Cost|Create_Date|Update_date|UserID|
```

This is my Login code:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(" Select * from New_User where User_Name=@USER_ID and Password=@PASS", conn);
    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("USER_ID", txtusername.Text.ToString()));
    String password = "";

    using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
    {
        // sha1.Initialize();
        byte[] data = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtpassword.Text));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
        {
            sb.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        password = sb.ToString();
    }

    selectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PASS", password));
    string UserType = null;

    SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    bool rowfound = reader.HasRows;

    if (rowfound)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            UserType = reader["User_Type"].ToString().Trim();

            if (UserType == "Administrator") 
            {
                GlobalVariablesClass.VariableOne = txtusername.Text;
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "Admin Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                Admin_Menu frm = new Admin_Menu();
                frm.bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = true;
                frm.Show();

                Stocks_Gems sg = new Stocks_Gems(); /*this is the UserControl: which has the grid-view*/ 
                sg.dataGridView1.Columns[10].Visible = true;  /*i have selected the 10th column which needed to be Visibile*/
                sg.Show();

                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (UserType == "StockController")
            {
                GlobalVariablesClass.VariableOne = txtusername.Text;
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome ", "User Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                Admin_Menu frm = new Admin_Menu();
                frm.bunifuFlatButton3.Visible = false;
                frm.Show();

                Stocks_Gems sg = new Stocks_Gems(); /*this is the UserControl: which has the grid-view*/ 
                sg.dataGridView1.Columns[10].Visible = false;  /*i have selected the 10th column which needed to be Hidden*/
                sg.Show();

                this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Invalid User Or Password ", "Login ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

The process of login 
User LOGIN > then MAIN MENU FORM opens > then Click button STOCK DETAILS > (on the right Grid-view) which is a USercontrol opens. but its  not affecting the column. please help!!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, creating hashed passwords without a changing salt is not a good idea. Heck, rolling your own security code is a bad idea unless you're a security expert.

Comment: What if the `UserType` is neither `Administrator` nor `StockController`?

Comment: there is only two User_Type

Comment: Thank you Racil Hilan for the for above comment i will change as u say!!

Comment: Even if there are only two types, the code is a security code and you don't want any chance for non-admins to see the hidden column. Instead of `if(admin) show elseif(controller) hide`, change it to `if(admin) show else hide`. This way you can guarantee that non-admins will never see the column even if there is something wrong with the database or a bug in the code. Also it is better to have the column originally hidden when the `dataGridView1` is created.

Answer (score 0):

If the `UserType` is neither `Administrator` nor `StockController`, your code for showing/hiding the column will not run and the column will keep the state that it currently has, which is most likely `Visible=true`.

Assuming that the above is not your issue and the user is guaranteed to be either `Administrator` nor `StockController`, you're likely issue is that the columns of your `dataGridView1` are auto-generated. For auto-generated columns, the `Visible` property will not work except in the [`DataBindingComplete` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx). See the [remarks for the `Visible` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.visible(v=vs.110).aspx):

> To hide a column that is automatically generated when binding to a data source, set this property in a DataBindingComplete event handler.

This will make it a little complicated to make your code working. It would be much easier if you set the `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`, and manually specify all your columns. Then your code will work without a change.

Comment: Thank you for the instant response. i tried this method its still showing the column for both the users.

Comment: Is there is any other solution

Comment: Setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` should work. You'll have to debug your code to see what's going on. I cannot think of anything else that prevents `Visible` from working.